# Adding 0 before month index in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am converting the `string` month to an index in javascript. But the number needs to have a 2 digit month representation.

This line of code converts the index for me and adds one. This way I have the correct month.

How can I add `0` to the front of the index if the value of the index is only 1 digit? So basically if the month is any of the first 9 months how do I add a 0 in front of the number value of the month?

```
var expMonth = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"].indexOf(req.body.expMonth.toLowerCase()) + 1;
```

March would output `3`. I need March to output `03`
But I need October, November, December to output 10, 11, 12. Which they do as of my code now.

Comment: Dulpicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method.

```js
console.log(
  ('0' + 1).slice(-2), 
  ('0' + 10).slice(-2), 
  ('0' + 3).slice(-2)
)
```

With your code :

```
var expMonth = ('0' + (["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"].indexOf(req.body.expMonth.toLowerCase()) + 1)).slice(-2);
```

Comment: See this is what I thought would work. And I keep trying that. but everytime I do this if the output. even with your code you gave me,  21 it appears to be adding the number 1 instead of the index plus one

Comment: It is concatenating the value instead of add index + 1

Comment: @wuno : updated

Comment: Awesome thank you. So basically I just had a syntax error. Would you mind explaining why that was happening to me? I will mark it as answered in 4 minutes.

Comment: @wuno :  now I just added parathesis for number addition for giving it higher priority... before it simply string concatenation is done

Comment: Ok thanks man. I was so close. Thanks for actually helping me out bro. have a good night.

Comment: @wuno : glad to help you